# Hibernate many-to-many self mapping read by .get()

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate for DBS mapping. I have Dokument class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOKU")
public class Dokument implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column
private String val;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "RELATIVES",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "DOK1_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "DOK2_ID")})
private Set<Dokument> iPoint = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "iPoint", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Dokument> pointMe = new HashSet<>();
```

And test code:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();


    Dokument dok = new Dokument("master");

    Dokument d1 = new Dokument("slave");
    dok.getiPoint().add(d1);

    session.save(dok);
    session.save(d1);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

It saves everything properly in DBS.
When I am trying to read it back by:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Dokument read = (Dokument) session.get(Dokument.class, 31);

System.out.println(read.getiPoint());

session.close();
```

I get stack overflow exception caused by getiPoint. session.get works itself.
Do you see any mistakes in code ? Thank you.

//edit
I let Netbeans to generate those methods, still same error

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 97 * hash + this.id;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Dokument other = (Dokument) obj;
    if (this.id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: maybe wrong equals/hashcode methods in Dokument ? Can you post the code for those methods ?

Comment: i did not implement those methods. Is it condition ?

Comment: Yeah, you should really implement those if you're going to put persisted objects in to a HashSet (or use them as keys in a HashMap).  Otherwise lookups won't work for the same Dokument loaded from two different Sessions (among other things).

Comment: Edited for equals and hashSet. Still same error

Comment: Paste the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: http://pastie.org/7112973

Answer (score 1):

The line of code that's giving you a problem is `System.out.println(read.getiPoint());` which is actually TWO operations.  Split them out to:

```
Set<Dokument> mySet = read.getiPoint();
System.out.println(mySet);
```

and re-run, and you will see that your `StackOverflowException` is coming from the second line.  Check the `Dokument.toString()` method, it is causing your problem.

Comment: Nope, same error. But error comes from prinline. Working on that, thanks for notice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, my big mistake. My Document.toString was:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Dokument{" + "id=" + id + ", val=" + val + ", iPoint=" + iPoint + ", pointMe=" + pointMe + '}';
}
```

so it keeps iPointing and iPointing. Sorry for my inattention.